# Android published app doesn't ask for internt permission

Tags: android, google-play

I made my first small android app that shows currency rates in widget. It needs internet permission. So I added this permission to manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Application fired on emulator and on my phone. But when I published it on google market - it doesn't ask for permissions. 
"App doesn not require any special permissions". 
And my app doesn't work. I think android blocks internet for my app.

build.grade:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my_widget.myelsewidget"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

What I did wrong?
Thanx!

***UPD: 
Surprize.***

I found that if I install app from the google play site (remotly from desktop) - it doesn't ask nothing and installs and works **well**.

And if I install it from google play app - it **doesn't fire**!

You can try it: the name is "**Currency wuzup**"

Comment: what's the target sdk in build.gradle?

Comment: Updated with build.grade

Comment: does the app work if you install release app on your device not from play store?

Comment: Yes, works. Maybe it's wrong, but I think it even worked in google play alfa testing mode

Comment: Interesting thing - post updated!

Comment: I've installed app, but I don't see app's icon...

Comment: Find it it widgets! It's widget

Comment: I've get NPE "Unable to start receiver com.my_widget.myelsewidget.MyProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
"

Comment: Yes, now there is a bug found - you have to set widget twice. First time it crashes. Bug fixing is in process. But anyway - the problem is other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it works everywhere. Maybe it was cache or google play bug or my phone's bug. 
Anyway - it doesn't ask for permissions, but works good. Strange thing.